# Notification icon does not load drawable due locale

Tags: android-notifications, android, android-location, android-notification-bar

I have created a simple Android app (https://github.com/soleimani/android-notification-locale) to notify a text, it has two button one loads default locale text and icon, other one loads "fa" locale. Image, notification title and notification text all respect locale, but notification icon is from default locale ("en")

```
    Button en = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEN);
    en.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            conf.locale = new Locale("en");
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            NotificationCompat.Builder overdueNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_service_content_text))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat);
            overdueNotification.setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_service_content_title));
            notificationManager.notify(1, overdueNotification.build());
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stat);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        }
    });

    Button fa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFA);
    fa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            conf.locale = new Locale("fa");
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            NotificationCompat.Builder overdueNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setContentText(getText(R.string.notification_service_content_text))
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat);
            overdueNotification.setContentTitle(getText(R.string.notification_service_content_title));
            notificationManager.notify(2, overdueNotification.build());
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stat);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        }
    });
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you can use user locale settings and android locale folders availability?